# How do I change color of a text when its clicked using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am trying hard to change the color of a text when it is clicked but not getting success.
There is one label for `question`, four labels for four `options`, one label for `correct answer` and one label for `explanation`.

What I am trying is when user click on any `option` then it should match with the `correct answer` and change the color of the text of that option i.e. when the answer is correct the text color should turn to green otherwise the color should turn to red .

But when I click on any `option` it is turning to red color only . Correct `option` should turn to green but it is turning to red . I can't figure out why ?.
Have a look at my code. Show me where I am making mistake and what is the solution.

**.aspx :-**

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Student/StudentPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="studpractice.aspx.cs" Inherits="Student_studpractice" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(function () {

            $(".optionclass").click(function () {
                var $thisoption = $(this);
                var $corrans = $(".correctans");

                if ($thisoption.text() == $corrans.text()) {
                    $thisoption.css("color", "green");
                } else {
                    $thisoption.css("color", "red");
                }
            });

        });


    </script>
    <div>
        <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Reasoning</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Quantitative Aptitude</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">English</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4">Mathematics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-5">Computer Concepts</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" width="100%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">

            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Question") %>'></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
           <span>A-</span><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="text-decoration:none;"> <asp:Label class="optionclass" ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Option1")%>' ></asp:Label></a>
            <br />
            <br />
            <span>B-</span><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="text-decoration:none;"> <asp:Label class="optionclass" ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Option2")%>'></asp:Label></a>
            <br />
            <br />
            <span>C-</span><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="text-decoration:none;"> <asp:Label class="optionclass" ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Option3")%>'></asp:Label></a>
            <br />
            <br />
            <span>D-</span><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="text-decoration:none;"> <asp:Label class="optionclass" ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Option4")%>'></asp:Label></a>
            <br />
            <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Button class="panelButton" runat="server" Text="Show Answer" ClientIDMode="Static" />
            <br />

            <asp:Panel ID="anspanel" class="AnswerPanel" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">

                <span>Correct Answer is :-</span><asp:Label class="correctans" ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CorrectAns")%>'></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Explanation")%>'></asp:Label>


            </asp:Panel>


        </asp:Panel>
        <br />
        <br />

                 </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
       
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">

            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Question") %>'></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
           <span>A-</span><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="text-decoration:none;"> <asp:Label class="optionclass" ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Option1")%>'></asp:Label></a>
            <br />
            <br />
            <span>B-</span><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="text-decoration:none;"> <asp:Label class="optionclass" ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Option2")%>'></asp:Label></a>
            <br />
            <br />
            <span>C-</span><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="text-decoration:none;"> <asp:Label class="optionclass" ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Option3")%>'></asp:Label></a>
            <br />
            <br />
            <span>D-</span><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="text-decoration:none;"> <asp:Label class="optionclass" ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Option4")%>'></asp:Label></a>
            <br />
            <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Button class="panelButton" runat="server" Text="Show Answer" ClientIDMode="Static" />
            <br />

            <asp:Panel ID="anspanel" class="AnswerPanel" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">

                <span>Correct Answer is :-</span><asp:Label class="correctans" ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CorrectAns")%>'></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Explanation")%>'></asp:Label>


            </asp:Panel>
        </asp:Panel>
        <br />
        <br />
                 </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        Tab 3 Content
    </div>
     <div id="tabs-4">
        Tab 4 Content
    </div>
     <div id="tabs-5">
        Tab 5 Content
    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btnPrevious" value="Previous" style = "display:none"/>
<input type="button" id="btnNext" value="Next" />


        </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: can you please put your html code here.

Comment: You first have to know if the answer is correct or not. Then change the color, which should not be hard.

Comment: Select only the .correctans not all of them, it obviously sets them all to red like this.

Answer (score 2):

So what wrong you are doing is you are selecting all `.correctans` and what you should do is select the `.correctans` specific to that question only.

Comment: I did modification in this line `var $corrans = $(this).parent().find(".AnswerPanel").children(".correctans");`....then also same problem occur .

Answer (score 0):

Change `$(".correctans")` to `$(".correctans")[0]` or `$(".correctans").first()` to get the single correctans element instead of a collection.

EDIT:

Since you have multiple questions and answers on the page, use this to get the correctans for the question they're answering:

`var $corrans = $(this).parent().find('.correctans:first');`

Comment: I used a panel which contain question, four options, correctAnswer and explanation and that panel is inside a gridview...so your solution is working only for first row of gridview.